# variable number of arguments (of different types) in ansi c

Tags: c

I am trying to resolve following problem... 

I have a function which should take following arguments:

```
change(input_file_name, output_file_name, pid1, pid1_file_name, pid2, pid2_file_name, etc... );
```

so in case of running of this function there will be:

```
change("input.file","output.file", 20, "file1.file", 21, "file2.file", 22, "file3.file", 23, "file4.file);
```

definition of this function is:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
int change(char input[], char output[], int n, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  unsigned int a;
  char *name;

  va_start(ap, n);

  ...

  for (; n; n-=2) {
    a = va_arg(ap, int);
    name = va_arg(ap,char *);

    ...

  }
  va_end(ap);
  return i;
}
```

but this does not work correctly. When trying to get "a" and "name" variables I get random data.

Comment: In the definition you have an additional `n` for the number of pid/name pairs that follow that you don't pass

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the argument for `n`.  As a result, everything else is off.

"20" is read as `n`, then "file1.file" as `a`, "21" as `name`, "file2.file" as `a`, etc.

Call the function like this:

```
                              //   v--- add this
change("input.file","output.file", 8, 20, "file1.file", 
                                      21, "file2.file", 
                                      22, "file3.file", 
                                      23, "file4.file");
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to function change isn't made correctly. The third parameter must be the count of trailing arguments.

Two trailing arguments. The third argument `2` corresponds to the third parameter in the definition of the function change, which is named `n`:

```
change("input.file", "output.file", 2, 20, "file1.file");
```

Eight trailing arguments:

```
change("input.file", "output.file", 8, 20, "file1.file", 21, "file2.file", 
                                       22, "file3.file", 23, "file4.file");
```

Both count and the trailing argument count must be divisible by two, since they are parsed in pairs.